# Lenovo g400s sound card doesnt work

Tags: sound, lenovo

I have bought a lenovo g400s with a dolby advanced audio v2 and soon enough I've installed Ubuntu.

But my surround sound doesn't work.

Is it supported?

I have tried countless tutorials on the internet but none of them work.

I have the latest kernel and latest Ubuntu.

More Info:

In that laptop I have a dolby advanced audio v2 surround speaker (I believe that is). When I play any music my alsa card says that is playing but unfortunately no sound comes out.

Jack works fine though.

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

I have tried to edit many config files related to alsa located in several question here in ask Ubuntu without success.

My hard info shows that:

[image: picture3]

Answer (score 0):

it's written on the laptop that some features are only available while running Microsoft windows as the device is built with windows 8 pre-installed . Running Ubuntu might be the cause of the problem :)